# How to load data from another sql file into a main sql file? - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, command-line

I am trying to process the scripts dbcreate_f.sql and dbload_f.sql to create and to load data into a script solution6.sql.

I am doing this in MYSQL command line.

In solution6.sql I have two statements:

```
source dbcreate_f.sql;
source dbload_f.sql;
```

These two files contain data to create tables and insert data into those tables. These two files are perfectly fine - no errors.

The problem I have though is when I run the actual solution6.sql script in MYSQL command line.

My steps are as shown:

```
tee solution6.rpt; 
source solution6.sql;
```

However, when the script processes in the command line I receive this error message everytime data is attempting to be inserted into each tabe:

```
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'bh576.AIRLINE' doesn't exist
```

I have run both the `dbcreate_f.sql` and `dbload_f.sql` script in mysql workshop and they run perfectly. The  problem only occurs in the command line interface.

Answer (score 1):

## POSSIBILITY #1

You need to check the table to see if it is damaged or corrupt

Please run the following:

```
USE bh576
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'AIRLINE';
SHOW CREATE TABLE AIRLINE \G
```

The first 2 Lines will verify the presence of `AIRLINE.frm`

The `SHOW CREATE TABLE AIRLINE \G` will reach out and attempt to retrieve `AIRLINE.frm` metadata. If this command complains by giving you that error

```
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'bh576.AIRLINE' doesn't exist
```

Then, the table is broken in terms of its attachment to the InnoDB data dictionary.

If you get this to work in MySQL Workshop every time, then a corrupt table is not the problem.

## POSSIBILITY #2

You need to make sure you are standing in a database.

It may be possible that the target database is not set in the `dbcreate_f.sql` script.

Before running the scripts, run this:

```
mysql> SELECT database();
```

This should return the name of the database you are loading.

If this comes back as `NULL` just change to the target database before running

```
USE mydb
source dbcreate_f.sql
source dbload_f.sql
```